# Passing dynamic array struct through function

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic, struct

```
struct aPoint {
        int somaVertical;
        int somaHorizontal;
        int valor;
};
```

I have an array of structs dynamically created in main(), like so:

```
struct aPoint *ps = malloc( sizeof(struct aPoint) * columns * rows )
```

And I want to work with its **struct values outside** of main() in a function that has `sscanf()`. The initialization of the array is also **taken care** of on the main().

How can I **pass** the **array of structs** through that function and set some **struct values** of it aswell? Argh I hate *pointering*!

Thanks!

Comment: +1 for coining the term "pointering" :)

Comment: Why are you multiplying the size by colunas and linhas? This will give you an array of structs, not just one.

Comment: Because I need an array of structs :P

Comment: OK, so are you passing them one at a time to readStuff, or do you want to pass the whole array of them?

Comment: OK I've updated my answer. `len` will be colunas * linhas.

Comment: We had _The Riddler_, now we have _The Pointerer_. I vote that all pointer related questions should subsequently begin with _POINTER ME THIS!_

Comment: 3 of the answers are perfectly valid and correct, and it works now. Now another dilemma, which answer to choose! :(

Comment: You can use calloc to initialise the struct fields to 0. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: The initialization of the struct fields was taken care of on the main(), what I needed is a way to set new values to them through this function. Thanks

Comment: I meant use calloc in main ;-).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That would be:

```
    int readStuff(struct aPoint *ps, size_t len, const char *someVar)
    {
        unsigned int i;
        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
           sscanf(someVar, "%d", &(ps[i].somaVertical));
           /* And so on for the other fields */
        }
        /* Return whatever you're returning here */
    }

    const size_t len = colunas * linhas;
    struct aPoint *ps = calloc(len, sizeof(struct aPoint));
    int success = readStuff(ps, len, arrayOfNumbers);
```

Comment: Most of the answers were pretty good and worked. I just choose the one that had more upvotes. Thanks everyone for the help.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me

```
/* #include <assert.h> */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct aPoint {
  int somaVertical;
  int somaHorizontal;
  int valor;
};

int readStuff(struct aPoint *data, int rows, int cols) {
  sscanf("42", "%d", &data[3].somaVertical);
  sscanf("142", "%d", &data[3].somaHorizontal);
  sscanf("-42", "%d", &data[3].valor);
  return 0;
}

int main(void) {
  struct aPoint *ps;
  int colunas, linhas;

  colunas = 80;
  linhas = 25;
  ps = malloc(sizeof *ps * colunas * linhas);
  /* assert(ps); */ /* thanks Tim */
  if (ps) {
    readStuff(ps, linhas, colunas);
    printf("%d %d %d\n", ps[3].somaVertical, ps[3].somaHorizontal, ps[3].valor);
    free(ps);
  } else {
    fprintf(stderr, "no memory.\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why the assertion instead of explicit `malloc()` failure checking? You know what `malloc()` returns when it fails. Why assert unless checking a condition that could happen beyond the return of a function? For instance, `assert(i != 3);` .. Your example means something like `NDEBUG` turns off checking the failure of `malloc()`, which is why assertions are sometimes categorized as evil.

Comment: @Tim: +1 ... I just added the assert (and the free) because I always say "check the return value of malloc" and I had failed to do that in this post. Thank you for pointing it out; I'm editing the post

Comment: upvoted, this answer took time and is the most helpful thus far. +2 if I could, as you made your example match the comments under it :)

Answer (score 0):

All functions in C are passed arguments by value, so you can pass a pointer to the struct array you wish to modify:

```
int readStuff(struct aPoint *p, int numStruct)
{
   ...
   for(i=0; i<numStruct; i++)
   {
      sscanf(someVar, "%d", &(*(p+i).valor) );
   }
   ...
}
```

You can call this function with:

```
struct aPoint *ps = malloc( sizeof(struct aPoint) * columns * rows );
...
readStuff(ps, columns * rows);
```

Comment: @Queops, sorry for the delay, I have edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need either

```
readStuff(ps); 
...
sscanf(someVar, "%d", &(ps[index].valor)); // using index in readStuff
```

or

```
readStuff(ps + index); // using index in main
...
sscanf(someVar, "%d", &(ps->valor)); // or &ps[0].valor, that's equivalent
```